# how do I get my data back from this closure?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, google-places-api

I'm new to closures in swift and was wondering how to get my annotations back from the closure. I understand that since it's asynchronous the outside array does not get filled up at the right time.

Should I use something like a completion handler? How do I do that? What is the best practice for this?  The function that has the callback is called from `didupdateLocation`.

```
 fileprivate func getGooglePoisForCurrentLocation(centerLatitude: Double, centerLongitude: Double, delta: Double, count: Int) -> Array<GMAnnotation>
        {
            var annotations: [GMAnnotation] = []

            placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Current Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods {
                    for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {

                        let annotation = GMAnnotation()
                        let place = likelihood.place

                        annotation.location = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)

                        annotations.append(annotation)
                    }


                }
            })

            return annotations;  ====> EMPTY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to add an `@escaping` closure to your function. Keep in mind that asynchronous functions change the way your application works — for example, if you're displaying this data in a table view, you'll need to call `tableView.reloadData()` (or one of its sibling methods) to actually update the table once the data is available. Here is your function with a closure:

```
fileprivate func getGooglePoisForCurrentLocation(centerLatitude: Double, centerLongitude: Double, delta: Double, count: Int, closure: @escaping (Array<GMAnnotation>) -> Void) {
    var annotations: [GMAnnotation] = []

    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
        if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods {
            for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {

                let annotation = GMAnnotation()
                let place = likelihood.place

                annotation.location = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)

                annotations.append(annotation)
            }
            closure(annotations)
        }
    })
}
```

When you call it, update your table view's datasource, then reload the table view:

```
getGooglePoisForCurrentLocationclosure(closure: { (annotations) -> Void in
    tableViewDataSourceArray = annotations
    tableView.reloadData()
})
```

As a side note, this example isn't particularly safe — there's no error checking, and the return type isn't optional — if the API call fails, it'll likely crash. Here's a more robust version of the same function, which handles the error and a proper return type:

```
enum PlacesResult {
    case success(Array<GMAnnotation>)
    case error(Error)
}

fileprivate func getGooglePoisForCurrentLocation(centerLatitude: Double, centerLongitude: Double, delta: Double, count: Int, closure: @escaping (PlacesResult) -> Void) {
    var annotations: [GMAnnotation] = []

    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Current Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            closure(PlacesResult.error(error))
        }
        if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods {
            for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {
                let annotation = GMAnnotation()
                let place = likelihood.place
                annotation.location = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
                annotations.append(annotation)
            }
            closure(PlacesResult.success(annotations))
        } else {
            closure(PlacesResult.error(Error()))
            // something else went wrong but we still want this to call the closure.
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `currentPlace` call is async, therefore you cannot immediatly return anything in your `getGooglePoisForCurrentLocation` function.

You *could* do something like this, depending on your needs:

- store the annotations in a private instance variable of the ViewController
- call some UI refresh code (like `tableView.reloadData` or somthing else in your ViewController) to update the UI. Be aware that such a call must be done in the main thread (you could use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to do so)